# Make drop down menu push content down on click

Tags: html, css

I am trying to push down my content whenever a user selects a links with a drop down menu. However, when clicked the dropdown goes over the content rather than pushes it down.

I have tried using position: relatives/position: absolute, etc to achieve some sort of desired result, but no such luck. I have seen other similar questions pertaining to this problem but it still has not helped me.

*Any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.*

**My HTML and CSS**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #eee;
}

.navbar-header {
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 0px !important;
}


/* for button placement*/

.navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 26px;
}


/*for collapsed navbar*/

.navbar-collapse {
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.site-logo {
  max-width: 135px;
  min-width: 120px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  color: #333333;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #3381d0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff5d1c;
  color: #ff5d1c;
  bottom: -2px;
}

.nav>li {
  position: static !important;
}


/* For navbar dropdown*/

.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 1349px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 51px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-top: 2px solid #ff5d1c;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333333;
  border-right: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-left: 0;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 75px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  color: #333333 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}

.m-pub {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 40px 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .14em;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -ms-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  position: relative;
}

.m-pub:after,
.m-pub:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}

.dropdown-menu li .m-pub:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid #333333;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
          <li class="nav-link active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu-trigger">Drop-Down Menu<i class="fa fa-angle-down flipped"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu">
              <li class="nav-link">
                <a href="#" class="m-pub"><i class="fa fa-microphone fa-2x"></i>Option</a>

              </li>
              <li class="nav-link">
                <a href="" class="m-pub"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-2x"></i>Option</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="container" style="background: red;height:100px; width: 100%;">

  </div>

</body>
```

I have provided a jsfiddle:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldayne/k8eayhxy/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your issue, as you suspected, is the positioning.  Unfortunately, if you use `position: absolute`, `.dropdown-menu` is removed from the flow of the document, winding up on top of anything beneath it rather than moving it out of the way.  If you use `position: relative` it forces it's parent to resize messing up your menu.  As far as I know there is no solution to this problem with pure CSS.  However, there is a few solutions with javascript, and since JQuery is already being used by bootstrap, we can just use that.

In order to move the content down when `dropdown-menu` is clicked you need to change either `.container`, the content, itself, or the parent/grandparent element that the `dropdown-menu` is relative to.  I chose to add `margin-bottom` the grandparent, which in this case, is the `nav` element.  You could just as easily add `margin-top` to `.container`.  Either way you need to set the margin equal to the height of `.dropdown-menu` which is set to `120px`.  I created the following rule to achieve this:

```
nav.navbar.open {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}
```

The extra class `.open` will be added by JQuery when `li.dropdown` is clicked.  I just used this quick bit of JQuery to acomplish this:

```
$("li.dropdown").click(function() {
  $("nav.navbar" ).toggleClass( "open");
});
```

That's all that is needed.  When `li.dropdown` is clicked a `.open` is added to the `nav` element which increases its bottom margin to the same height of `.dropdown-menu`.  The margin doesn't affect `.dropdown-menu` since it's absolutely positioned and instead only pushes down `.container` just as if `.dropdown-menu` was not removed from the document flow.  The reason for using `li.dropdown` and not `#menu-trigger` (the link itself) is because if you use the link, and then click on `.dropdown-menu` the menu is dismissed, but the margin remains.  By using the parent of `dropdown-menu` the click event is still registered whenever a child of the parent is clicked.  If a sibling is used then the trigger doesn't happen.

```js
$("li.dropdown").click(function() {
  $("nav.navbar").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar {
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #eee;
}
.navbar-header {
  margin-top: -12px;
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 0px !important;
}
/* for button placement*/

.navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 26px;
}
/*for collapsed navbar*/

.navbar-collapse {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
.site-logo {
  max-width: 135px;
  min-width: 120px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  color: #333333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #3381d0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff5d1c;
  color: #ff5d1c;
  bottom: -2px;
}
.nav>li {
  position: static !important;
}
/* For navbar dropdown*/

.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 1349px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 51px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-top: 2px solid #ff5d1c;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333333;
  border-right: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-left: 0;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 75px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  color: #333333 !important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
.m-pub {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 40px 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .14em;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -ms-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  position: relative;
}
.m-pub:after,
.m-pub:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
.dropdown-menu li .m-pub:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid #333333;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  background: none;
}
nav.navbar.open {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
          <li class="nav-link active"><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu-trigger">Drop-Down Menu<i class="fa fa-angle-down flipped"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu">
              <li class="nav-link">
                <a href="#" class="m-pub"><i class="fa fa-microphone fa-2x"></i>Option</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-link">
                <a href="" class="m-pub"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-2x"></i>Option</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container" style="background: red;height:100px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

The snippet is small enough that it engages the mobile view, so you'll need to view it in full screen.  Or you can check out the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbBPPY).

As a note of caution, some of the stylings you have added for `.dropdown-menu` break the mobile version, so you may want to take a look at them, or add some media queries to fix them up a bit.

Comment: Thanks you for that great answer! Your explanation has helped me out quite a lot.

Comment: whenever I open the drop down and click somewhere else on the page the menu disappears but the margin remains the same. Is there a way around this issue that doesn't involve toggleClass()? @David Mann

Comment: I tried adding a listener to the whole document to get ride of the open class when anything was clicked.  Unfortunately, it seems that bootstrap is stopping the propagation, so that the event is never triggering.  The only way I can think of to fix that would be to dig through bootstraps code. and either modify the function doing the original task to toggle the class, or to stop it from halting the propagation.

Comment: Here's the function I was trying, but I have no way of knowing if it works due to the conflict with bootstrap. `$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest('li.dropdown').length || $(nav.navbar).hasClass("open")) {
    $("nav.navbar").toggleClass("open");
  }
});`

Comment: I was able to solve my problem [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldayne/k8eayhxy/4/)... Thanks againg for your help @David Mann

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap accordion, it uses bootstrap css and you can use a single accordion item as a drop down to push content down, this is bootstrap code so you can just copy and depending on whether you want it closed or opened just use `class="collapse"` or `class="show"` respectively. use accordion as a dropdown wherever you want it in your navigation bar

```
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the third item's accordion body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms of content, but just filling up the space to make it look, at least at first glance, a bit more representative of how this would look in a real-world application.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).